# Non-drawing Mozilla plug-in

Tags: c++, firefox, npapi

I have some dll that implements some logic. I want to create wrapper that will be accessible from JavaScript of HTML page  in Mozilla Firefox browser. I have found npruntime framework, but it seems supports only window control, i don't need GUI. I am looking for mechanism like ActiveXObject implemented in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI). Its documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference) on MDC, [here](http://colonelpanic.net/2009/03/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-one/) is an excellent tutorial for it.

There are alternatives to doing it directly however, [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) can generate code to interface NPAPI (if i remember that right) and there is also [FireBreath](http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/) which hides browser and platform differences from you.

NPAPI was designed to display alternative content in websites, thus non-drawing plugins aren't explicitly supported. If you know however that your plugin won't get shown in the page anyway (i.e. the object or embed element will be hidden anyway), you don't have to do anything in `NPP_SetWindow()` or if you get drawing events in `NPP_HandleEvents()`. Alternatively you can just draw some static background.

The best equivalent to `ActiveXObject()` would be to have a factory method for your plugin that creates new scriptable objects, i.e. something like `myPlugin.createObject()`.

Comment: I have found there:

You can write plug-ins that are drawn in their own native windows or frames on a web page.

But i don't need GUI.

Comment: You can simply use window-less plugins: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference:Plug-in_Basics#Windowed_and_Windowless_Plug-ins ... and even with windowed plugins, you don't *need* to do drawing.

Comment: The best equivalent to `ActiveXObject` would probably be a factory method on your plugins that returns new scriptable objects.

Comment: I don't need to do drawing, but must plug-in  implement drawing function?

Comment: You can just do nothing on `NPP_SetWindow()` or incoming drawing events coming in on `NPP_HandleEvent()` if you don't want to draw and you expect users to not show your plugin in the page (i.e. the embed or object element is hidden). Alternatively, just draw a black background or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! I've get that solution before,but hoped for clean windowless solution.

Comment: It has historic reasons, NPAPI was designed for displaying alternative/unsupported content in websites.